# Android - Somar um double toda vez que a função for chamada

Tags: java, android

Como faço para que uma função some sempre um valor double a outro, pois o onClick() soma apenas uma vez.

MainActivity.java:

```
Button somar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

double a = 20;
double b = 20;
double c = a + b;

somar.setOnClickListener(
new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View p1){
    txt.setText(c);

}
```

Comment: Isso não é verdade. Coloque seu código para darmos uma olhada.

Comment: Na verdade eu fiz a pergunta errada. O que eu quero é que uma função some sempre um valor double a outro. Vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sempre que clicar no botão ele vai somar a+b é isso? 
Se for você não pode deixar a variável estática dessa forma.

```
Button somar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

double a = 20;
double b = 20;
double c = 0;

somar.setOnClickListener(
new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View p1){
    c = c + (a+b);
    txt.setText(c);
}
```

Dessa forma por exemplo temos:

1° Clique - 40;

2° Clique - 80;

3° Clique - 120;

....

Comment: Valeu ai! Exatamente o que precisava!